# WaitForEndOfFrame replacing WaitForNewFrame

Tags: unity-game-engine

The following strategy was suggested, in order to allow some time for a big system to finish all the loading, etc...

So, the idea is to make sure I have waited for long enough for everything to be loaded, and then do my own command. Let's call it `CMD()` for now.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine( TakeYourTime() );
}

IEnumerator TakeYourTime()
{
   yield return new WaitForNewFrame();
   yield return new WaitForNewFrame();
   yield return new WaitForNewFrame();
   yield return new WaitForNewFrame();

   CMD();
}
```

But of course, Unity3D does not recognize `WaitForNewFrame()`!

After googling, I realized there is only `WaitForEndOfFrame()` available, so I replaced it in the above, thinking that it would achieve the same, but my `CMD()` does not take effect.

So, I am wondering if **this existing command is not the same as the originally-suggested one**, or if **I am not waiting long enough**?

Comment: WaitForNewFrame is ***absolutely wrong***.  never use it for any reason.  WaitForEndOfFrame is ***absolutely wrong***.  never use it for any reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   yield return null;
```

is the command that will get the method to return on next frame and continue.

But this is no good practice as you cannot know if one , two or more frames are required.

You should have some kind of control over the flow of your program. If some actions are long and spread over several frames, provide a callback to the coroutine:

```
void Awake()
{
    StartCoroutine(Loading(CMD));
}

private void CMD(){ //Other actions }

private IEnumerator Loading (Action action)
{
     // Many long action with yield
     if(action != null) { action(); } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If `CMD()` is also an IEnumerator function, you have to do another `StartCoroutine()` function on it, or it will not work. Based on the information available that's the only issue I can think of to explain why `CMD()` would not start.

If you have additional logic after that requires to wait on the completion of `CMD()`, you can `yield return` the `StartCoroutine()` call to pause `TakeYourTime()` from continuing until `CMD()` is completed.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine( TakeYourTime() );
}

IEnumerator TakeYourTime()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    yield return StartCoroutine(CMD());

    //Do the rest.
}

IEnumerator CMD() 
{
    //Do whatever.
}
```

If `CMD()` is not an IEnumerator function, then I apologize for this incorrect answer. You can troubleshoot further using `Debug.Log()` calls to determine where the application is getting stuck. I would put them before, after, and on the first line of `CMD()`

From your comments, though, I would recommend you do something else.

You mention that when you wait longer, it works. That means you're just waiting on something to complete, and there's no issue with methods firing.

You should do something like this instead:

```
IEnumerator TakeYourTime()
{
    while(!otherThingIsFinished()) 
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
    CMD();
}
```

`otherThingIsFinished()` should be a call to check to see if the stuff you're waiting for has completed whatever it's doing. You can have a public method that you can call that checks some private boolean that gets set when it's completed.

You can also just have the other stuff call this method directly, although that may not be the best option either. It all depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Many thanks. I actually learned something new from the first part of your answer, so that is great. `CMD()` is not an `IEnumerator` and I could not find anything by googling both `Unity` and `WaitForNewFrame` so I am guessing that particular command does not exist (anymore) but anyhow, I used `yield return new WaitForSeconds(5)` instead and it works. Cheers

Comment: WaitForNewFrae does not exist. This is the reason why you cannot find anything about it and why this answer is providing false direction.

Comment: never use WaitForEndOfFrame for any reason -  ever.

Comment: I meant to fix the WaitForNewFrame section, as it doesn't exist. I apologize for my mistake in that regard.  @Jtech: If you're simply waiting for something else to complete, it may be a good idea to have a value you can check in your `TakeYourTime()` function so that you can be sure it's completed before you attempt to do the rest of your command.

Comment: @Polantaris + all: Many thanks everyone. It is resolved. Cheers